# Mac Flash Builder cannot locate debugger

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, macos, debugging, flash-builder

I've started getting the following when I try to run FB4 projects:

> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin
>
> Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the debugger version of the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder.

I've installed the debugger version of the Flash Player. Didn't work. I've reinstalled Flash Builder. Didn't work. I tried using Safari instead of Firefox. Didn't work.

When I go to Macintosh HD/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ in the finder, I can see  Flash Player.plugin right there. But when I go to Username/Library/Internet Plug-Ins the entire folder is blank. So I tried copying Flash Player.plugin to the latter folder. Didn't work.

Mac questions (I'm new to mac): Which of these is really the root? Is it normal that there should be duplicate directories like this, with non-duplicate contents??

In FB I opened Windows --> preferences --> Flash Builder --> Profiler --> Player/Browser and browsed to /Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Players/Debug/Flash Player Debugger.app

Flash question: What does Flash Player Debugger.app have to do with Flash Player.plugin?

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would uninstall flash player first. For whatever reason, in the past when I've tried installing debugger over an existing normal flash player plug-in I have that same problem on a mac.

Uninstaller can be found here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Debugger installers can be found here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

After you have the old player removed and the debugger installed, check out this site for instructions on how to setup trace output for terminal debugging: [http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2009/12/11/tips-n-tricks/tip-output-trace-statements-through-terminal/](http://www.visible-form.com/blog/view-trace-statements-in-the-terminal-on-os-x/)

Hope this helps :-)

-p

Comment: Sorry -- ignore the above. That pretty much did it, Philip, thanks. I first uninstalled, then went to the downloads page. I clicked on Download the Macintosh Flash Player 10.1 Plugin content debugger (Intel-based Macs)  and that had me download flashplayer_10_plugin_debug_ub.dmg. I installed it. But then hen I went to http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/865/cpsid_86551.html#ostype=m,prob1=dwnld,prob2=instintelmac,os=m10.6, it showed Debug Player: No. So it still wasn't seeing it, and I still couldn't debug in FB4. I then did a search for "Install Adobe Flash Player Debugger" on my machine. (cont'd)

Comment: It showed me the little red Flash folder icon, which I double-clicked. It seems to run the same install_flash_player_osx_ub.dmg file but for some reason it now worked: I saw Debug Player:Yes at the above URL and then FB4 debugging worked as well. I add all this in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: The last link didn't load for me.

Comment: @wayfarer -- this link works and has the same info http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2009/12/11/tips-n-tricks/tip-output-trace-statements-through-terminal/